# Is it possible to perform browser automation of a hidden javascript form with selenium (ruby bindings prefered)

Tags: javascript, selenium, mechanize

I am about to dive into selenium, but before i would like to ask wether what i want to do is actually possible or impossible.

The case is a NGO that some time ago had a website app done for free, where volunteers can register and it all shows up nicely in a database. Sometimes volunteers are not able to register on their own and they just send it by mail so we have to do it. There are up to 4000 in the big food collection (once a year) so its a big deal.

I want to read the emails with ruby and use the info extracted to fill in the forms automatically, but using mechanize has only got me to log in and then reach the new-volunteer registration form. This form appears to be a javascript Jquery or sth of the sort, and i cant access it because it reads the js from a file, and the company that developed it is not reachable.

I have researched a bit and found that selenium would be the best alternative, ..  but is it possible at all without having access to the javascript code?

Below a pretty print of the page where the form is (iframe), thanks.

```
#<Mechanize::Page
 {url
  #<URI::HTTP:0x2a41508 URL:http://www.bancodealimentosdesevilla.org/portal/group/zona-de-gestion#main-content>}
 {meta_refresh}
 {title "Zona de Gesti\u00F3n - Banco de alimentos"}
 {iframes #<Mechanize::Page::Frame nil "javascript:false">}
 {frames}
 {links
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Saltar al contenido" "#main-content">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   " Banco de alimentos "
   "http://www.bancodealimentosdesevilla.org/portal/web/guest/inicio">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   " Zona de Gesti\u00F3n "
   "http://www.bancodealimentosdesevilla.org/portal/group/zona-de-gestion/inicio?p_p_auth=Ts9S8fV0&p_p_id=49&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_count=1&_49_struts_action=%2Fmy_places%2Fview&_49_groupId=11232&_49_privateLayout=true">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Zona P\u00FAblica" "/portal/">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "Zona Voluntarios"
   "/portal/group/zona-de-voluntarios">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Zona Gesti\u00F3n" "/portal/group/zona-de-gestion">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Salir" "/portal/c/portal/logout">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "S\u00EDguenos en Facebook"
   "http://www.facebook.com/B.Alim.Sev">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "S\u00EDguenos en Twitter"
   "http://twitter.com/b_alim_sev">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   " Zona de Gesti\u00F3n"
   "/portal/group/zona-de-gestion/inicio">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "" nil>
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "" nil>
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "Pol\u00EDtica de Privacidad"
   "/portal/web/guest/politica-privacidad">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "S\u00EDguenos en Facebook"
   "http://www.facebook.com/B.Alim.Sev">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "S\u00EDguenos en Twitter"
   "http://twitter.com/b_alim_sev">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Powered By CommerZZia" "http://www.comerzzia.es">}
 {forms
  #<Mechanize::Form
   {name "hrefFm"}
   {method "POST"}
   {action ""}
   {fields}
   {radiobuttons}
   {checkboxes}
   {file_uploads}
   {buttons}>}>
```

Comment: If the page loads fine in a web browser, then you can manipulate it with Selenium because it is driving a full browser like Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: It loads fine, i will give it a shot then, thanks!

Comment: Why not use some kind of email interacting library and directly scrape the messages from there. There would be no need to hit the front end at all. Example https://github.com/mikel/mail

Comment: The company that developed the app is not reachable, therefore we have no access to the backend. Or did i not understand right?